# ethminer invalid argument: -S

Tags: go-ethereum

using below to mine

```
ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -S asia1.ethpool.org:3333 -FS us1.ethpool.org:3333 -O a9a777fc5cfc9589e413635b0b878ae4061fda2
```

but it said

> 'Invalid argument: -S'

Any suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are using are for [qtminer](http://qtminer.exe%20-s) not ethminer

to get it work, install and run e[th-proxy](http://ethpool.org/) then run :

```
./ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -F http://127.0.0.1:8080/rig1
```

check the available options [here](https://gist.github.com/jmiehau/0470ef3262d83987221e).